# Node.JS proxy with Nginx and Docker

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container with nodejs and I have a docker container with nginx.

I have told my angular to use ec2-xxx:8888/api to use the api's.
Because I ran my nodejs container with:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name nodejs localhost:5000/test/node-js-image:1
```

So I mapped the 8888 of my docker on my amazon. So this is working.
My app.config.js contains:

```
URL: 'http://ec2...',
      PORT: '8888',
```

I can see my api's on `ec2:8888/api`
But it's not save to make your api accessible with the server. So I would like to run my nodejs like this:

```
docker run -d --name nodejs localhost:5000/test/node-js-image:1
```

So without mapping the container port on the port of my amazon. But I still need to access the nodejs container from my nginx container.

How can I do this?
I tried in my nginx.conf:

```
http {    
        upstream node-app {
              least_conn;
              server nodejs:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;

        }

        server {
              listen 80;

              location / {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/;
                index index.html;
              }

              location /api {
                proxy_pass http://node-app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

But this isn't working. I only see HTML (no CSS) and it's not possible to connect with the nodeJS container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both containers run on the same machine, Docker's [**legacy** container links](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) are one possibility. [Networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/) is the new way to go.

Start your nodejs container with

```
docker run -d --name nodejs --expose 8888 <YOUR_NODEJS_IMAGE>
```

In contrary to `-p ...` the option `--expose ...` makes your container only visible to linked containers.

Start your nginx container with the link to nodejs:

```
docker run -d --name nginx --link nodejs <YOUR_NGINX_IMAGE>
```

In order to access the nodejs docker container from your nginx docker container you must use environment variables injected by docker. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/xaviervia/6adea3ddba269cadb794) gives an example on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, Now I'm able to see my api on ec:80/api (without mapping the 8888). But I still have problems with my static files. They're showing in pure HTML and there seems to be no connection with the API.

Comment: The response is: failed to reponse data: and its going to ec:8888/api/app. (Should I edit my app.config.js to use port 80 now?)

Comment: Please make sure that you configured nginx properly as shown in the gist.